# Selecting columns from a data file in Python

Tags: python

I have a data file that looks like this

```
0,000   1024,000    1017,000
0,897   1024,000    1017,000
1,896   1024,000    1017,000
2,897   1024,000    1017,000
3,896   1024,000    1017,000
4,897   1024,000    1017,000
```

I want to select the second and third column and put them in two seperate lists but I don't know how to. This is what I have got so far:

```
file = open('data_file',"r")
file_content = file.read()
file.close()
```

I have made some tries selecting a full column but haven't gotten it to work. How should I go about it?

Comment: you want to separate the columns by white spaces or the comma ","

Comment: Take a look at [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split). You can also read the file line by line by writing: `for line in file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Pandas is another way. Nice thing of pandas is it's built ins to deal with different types of number formatting and file layouts

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('in.txt', header=None, delimiter="\s+")  #, thousands=",")

print(df)
print(list(df[2].values))

      0        1        2
0     0  1024000  1017000
1   897  1024000  1017000
2  1896  1024000  1017000
3  2897  1024000  1017000
4  3896  1024000  1017000
5  4897  1024000  1017000

#[1017000, 1017000, 1017000, 1017000, 1017000, 1017000]
# with the thousands="," removed the values remain strings
['1017,000', '1017,000', '1017,000', '1017,000', '1017,000', '1017,000']

# Or rename the columns
df.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']

print(list(df['C'].values))
# [1017000, 1017000, 1017000, 1017000, 1017000, 1017000]
['1017,000', '1017,000', '1017,000', '1017,000', '1017,000', '1017,000']
```

Comment: How can I import pandas as PyCharm is saying that there is no module with that name?

Comment: it is not part of the standard environment. So you need to install it: *pip install pandas*

Comment: This works nicely but it does cause the comma's to drop out. How do I fix that?

Comment: I assumed these are numbers with a thousand separator ','. If you want to calculate with the numbers you need to get rid of the ','. In case you don't need to calculate, simply remove the *thousands=","* from the *read_csv(...)*

Answer (score 2):

You can read the lines in and then filter to just the last two columns.  From there, you can use `zip` to turn the columns into a list.

```
with open('data_file') as f:
    lines = [line.split() for line in f.readlines()]

columns = [[col[1], col[2]] for col in lines]

print(list(list(col) for col in zip(*columns)))
```

`zip` is tricky if you just read its description.  Much better to fiddle with it like this to understand how it works:

```
list(zip((2,4,6),(1,3,5)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a library for that, but one way without libraries is just to create a list and create sublist with separator. Should be something like this:

```
file = open('data_file',"r")
file_content = file.read().splitlines() # create file_content list with each row
file.close()

seperate_list = [] # create seperate list with second and third row
for value in file_content[1].split('   '): # iterates through sublist using separator
    seperate_list.append(value)
for value in file_content[2].split('   '):
    seperate_list.append(value)
print(seperate_list) # print a list with second and third row values
```

Of course that is considering the 3 blank space separator woudn't change in the `data_file`.